# Firebase - Firestore data structure

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I need help best approach how to structure collection and documents.
What I am wanting to achieve is simple in a traditional sql query.

I have collection of cards, each card with a id.
I have a collection of users that earn cards and store the card id.
I want to filter a user cards.
Traditional sql

```
SELECT cards.cardID, cards.CardName, cards.CardDescription, myCards.uid 
FROM cards 
INNER JOIN myCards ON cards.cardID = myCards.cardID 
WHERE (((myCards.uid)=1));
```

I know it not done like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of a server-side join in Cloud Firestore (nor in many other NoSQL databases).

If you need data from two collections, you'll need (at least) two read operations.

Alternatively, you can duplicate data from `myCards` into the relevant documents in the `cards` collection. In that case you stored duplicate data, but need fewer read operations. You're trading off the scalability of your read operations, for more complex (and less scaleable) write operations.

Which of these approaches you prefer depends largely on your experience level with NoSQL databases. Neither is always better than the other. To get more comfortable with these considerations, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ).